# Perl's glob equivalent in Shell to loop though the files matching pattern

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
$ #Have no Blog* file in /tmp.
$ ls /tmp/*log*
/tmp/AlogA123.txt  /tmp/logA123.txt

$ for i in /tmp/logA* /tmp/Alog* /tmp/Blog*; do echo "will do something here with $i"; done
will do something here with /tmp/logA123.txt
will do something here with /tmp/AlogA123.txt
will do something here with /tmp/Blog*
```

Why is the last line getting printed as the file don't exist, is there a way to avoid?

Answer (score 1):

Enable the shell option `nullglob` so that the `/tmp/Blog*` will expand to nothing when it doesn't match any files:

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

`-s` is used to set a shell option and `-u` is used to unset it, so to restore the default behaviour use this:

```
shopt -u nullglob
```

Comment: thanks, and how to revert (revert nullglob) back after I am done in the shell?

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the last line getting printed as the file don't exist, is there
>   a way to avoid?

Yes, it getting printed because you've three values to be read in sequence. It is successfully being expanded in the shell :

```
for i in /tmp/logA* /tmp/Alog* /tmp/Blog*;
```

You should instead add the

```
for file in /tmp/*log*
do
#// do whatever
done
```